# Serving images from outside of document root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is it possible?

Let's say my directory structure looks like this:

```
/data
    /data/images
/public
```

The document root is in the "public" directory. This won't work, of course:

```
<img src="/../data/images/1.png" alt="" />
```

But maybe it's possible to enable serving images from directory above document root somehow? I would like to know.

Comment: Well, there are several ways, like `symlink`.   
But it would be impossible to give the right answer before you tell us, what's the purpose of storing images outside of document root

Comment: You could use .htaccess to rewrite any incoming requests to an image to pass through an image serving script, but then again, why would you want to do such a thing? It's not like this would protect your images from anything. Once it shows in the browser, it's on the client.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most common way is an [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias):

```
Alias /data/ /wherever/your/data/are/
```

Comment: +1 this needs to be put into `httpd.conf` itself, though, it won't work in a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: +1, i used this method to to try and keep as many document out of the public_html for security.

Comment: @Robert umm, how would that add any security?

Comment: I ment securty as i store my execution file such as php outside the html root scope and include from a directory root, I would not be worried about public files such as js, just saying that its better to generally store files outside the public root. - php files are safe from injection attempts and out of public's way.

Comment: +1 This is exactly the right answer.  In httpd.conf it says, verbatim `"Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot."`

Comment: @RobertPitt - I think what Gordon was trying to say is that this method allows any user to navigate to `http://yourserver/data` and they'll see everything in the folder anyway (like his comment in the OP suggests).

Comment: This solution is valid, unless you are generating dynamic content, in PHP for example, or any system that references files via the actual filesystem, not Apache...  Paths like `(dirname(__FILE__)` will not work with an Apache alias, so if you are serving anything but static content, I would investigate other solutions, such as symlinks, server-side includes, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Another way (say if you can't set an alias...) would be to use a script as the image source eg:

```
<img src="image.php?img=myImage.jpg" />
```

image.php would be similar to:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
  readfile("../img/" . $_GET['img']);
?>
```

Of course you'd need to extend the script to filter $_GET['img'], as well as detect and set the right content type. Your script could even resize the image according to other parameters passed in the query string.