# I want to display the image from xampp folder?

Tags: image

Working with PHP. I want to display the images which are in xampp folder not in htdocs (which will be root of the website). How to go about it? I have tried `<img src="../../image.jpg"`, and also tried with `src=/image.jpg`, not working. Given the total path as `src="E:/xampp/image.jpg`" still not working. What may be wrong. The file is .php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serving images from outisde of document root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131562/serving-images-from-outisde-of-document-root)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access pictures (or files) outside of htdocs on a webpage.

There are probably ways to retrieve the image from a directory "lower" than htdocs with PHP (depending on your open_basedir-restrictions), store them somewhere else and let the img-tag display them or really mess with your server settings to allow access ... but why don't you just place the images somewhere in htdocs (or a subdirectory), where they belong?

Answer (score 0):

You cant access images/css sheets etc outside htdocs folder
Make a folder for images in htdocs and use those